# Unity game with Google Admob crashes on startup

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob

i made a game in unity and use Google Admob to show ads in my game. The last Year it worked well. For some time now (I don't check my game on iOS every day) the game crashes as soon as it is started.
I have connected my iPhone to XCode. The following is displayed in the console.
Can you tell from this what the problem is? What could be the problem?

If you need other logs, please tell me where I can find them in XCode or wherever, because I'm not that familiar with Xcode.

```
2024-01-01 22:31:18.212416+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Created
2024-01-01 22:31:18.213225+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Registered for lifecycle events
2024-01-01 22:31:18.509487+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] Built from '2022.3/release' branch, Version '2022.3.12f1 (4fe6e059c7ef)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2024-01-01 22:31:18.510322+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] MemoryManager: Using 'Default' Allocator.
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-allocator-temp-initial-block-size-main=262144"
    "memorysetup-allocator-temp-initial-block-size-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
[Physics::Module] Initialized MultithreadedJobDispatcher with 5 workers.
2024-01-01 22:31:18.868387+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] UnityIAP UnityEarlyTransactionObserver: Added to the payment queue
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1; jobified=0
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A12 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2022.3.12f1 (4fe6e059c7ef)
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
2024-01-01 22:31:19.429237+0100 Tolf[5750:687971]  - <Google>[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), ca-app-pub-8024607594252244~7980677582
2024-01-01 22:31:19.429399+0100 Tolf[5750:687971]  - <Google>[I-ACS023007] Analytics v.71100000 started
2024-01-01 22:31:19.429779+0100 Tolf[5750:687971]  - <Google>[I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see XXX_WEBSITE_XXX)
2024-01-01 22:31:19.481588+0100 Tolf[5750:687970]  - <Google>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2024-01-01 22:31:19.521723+0100 Tolf[5750:687970]  - <Google>[I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
UnloadTime: 3.780042 ms
2024-01-01 22:31:22.062981+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] <Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"0547383af6c0b80194e582328a10bfd0" ];
2024-01-01 22:31:22.147804+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] <Google> Note that test device identifiers may be reset when uninstalling and reinstalling the application.
2024-01-01 22:31:22.493641+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
2024-01-01 22:31:22.493698+0100 Tolf[5750:687721] [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
2024-01-01 22:31:22.537797+0100 Tolf[5750:687970] <Google> <Google:HTML> You are currently using version 7.69.0 of the SDK, which is deprecated. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version (10.12.0) to get the latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from XXXWebsiteXXX. More information about the SDK deprecation schedule is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/deprecation.
HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad event received with message: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show.
X3VideoAd:HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(Object, AdErrorEventArgs)
GoogleMobileAds.iOS.RewardedAdClient:RewardedAdDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCallback(IntPtr, String)

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper
```

I suspect that I need to update the SDK in unity somehow. But I don't know if that's the real problem. I haven't found a way to update it yet either. Under the given link I only find different SDKs for Android and Apple. Originally I had one SDK for both systems.

Answer (score 0):

you received the log " Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show."
It means that ad is not ready from server side, If your app crashes a few times , then you should call ads with try catch pattern, It will save audience and reduce the crashes!
Hope it should work !
Mustakeem !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what exactly do you mean by try catch pattern? 
What does that mean?

Comment: @Berlin-Koeln, [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements) is a statement to handle the exceptions that you may receive in your code, and you can also perform different actions based on what exception you receive.

Comment: But there is a difference in how it is being handled inside Unity, Please take a look at this thread on Unity Forum [C# try catch doesn't seem to work](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-try-catch-doesnt-seem-to-work.24743/)

Comment: I tried to use the test ad ids instead of my ad ids. That worked well. So is there a problem with my ad ids? 

For the moment my ads are blocked by admob because there was a bug with the reward.  
Could this be the reason why no ads can be loaded and the app crashes as a result?   

The problem is that I can't upload the new app version to get my ads activated again because the app crashes. 

But I also can't have the blocking lifted by ADmob because the bug still exists in the current version.